# Gmail markup, event reservation, location name without reservation number

Tags: email, gmail, location, google-schemas

I'm trying to understand Google's gmail markup for event reservation - https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation.
I want to include only selected portion of data to my customers, such as event name, event location address, location address, date, etc.
And I don't want to send `reservationNumber`. But when I don't send `reservationNumber`, the location name isn't displayed. Have a look, the only difference is the `reservationNumber` presence.

**How I can make gmail display my location name without reservation number provided?**

This is my `<script type='application/ld+json'>`:

```
{  
  "@context":"http://schema.org",
  "@type":"EventReservation",
  "modifyReservationUrl":"https://facebook.com",
  "underName":{  
    "@type":"Person",
    "name":"John Doe"
  },
  "reservationFor":{  
    "name":"Event Name",
    "startDate":"2019-02-13T12:00:00Z",
    "endDate":"2019-02-13T13:00:00Z",
    "location":{  
      "name":"Location name",
      "address":{  
        "streetAddress":"Twarda 18",
        "addressLocality":"Warszawa",
        "addressRegion":null,
        "postalCode":null,
        "addressCountry":"PL"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And screens, mentioned above:

[without reservationNumber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXadc.png)

[with reservationNumber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9xzB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out, what was missing...

Whole section `reservationFor` was missing `@type`.
The below works like a charm:

```
"reservationFor":{  
    "@type":"Event",
    "name":"Event Name",
    "startDate":"2019-02-13T12:00:00Z",
    "endDate":"2019-02-13T13:00:00Z",
    "location":{  
      "@type":"Place",
      "name":"Location name",
      "address":{  
        "@type":"PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress":"Twarda 18",
        "addressLocality":"Warszawa",
        "addressRegion":null,
        "postalCode":null,
        "addressCountry":"PL"
      }
    }
  }
```